# Passing html throgh ajax to wcf service

Tags: ajax, wcf

I want to pass html content for example the body content to a wcf service through ajax call, its saying URL is too long.  Can this be solved

Answer (score 0):

Assign html content in javascript variable and use below code.

```
var html_content= "<html...content>";
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",//file_name
        type: "POST",
        data: {
               content: html_content
       },
});
```